# ObservableCollection Implementation

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I know I am missing something obvious but I can't seem to implement ObservableCollection in my class below. IE it won't show up in intellsense.  Can someone please let me know what I am missing.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Reflection;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyBTOList
{
public class InventoryListBTO : List<InventoryBTO>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get all inventory records from local database
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static InventoryListBTO GetAllInventoryRecords()
    {
        return GetInventoryListBO(Inventory.GetAllInventoryRecordsDb());
    }
 }

 public class InventoryBTO : INotifyPropertyChanged
 {

 }
```

Comment: Where's ObservableCollection? Do you mean INotifyPropertyChanged? InventoryBTO has no implementation, you need to implement something.  And what is GetInventoryListBO?  It can't be a method on InventoryBTO, because there is no implementation.

Comment: Does it compile, if not, then what errors?  Sometimes Intellisenseless won't display your new code until at least one compile.

Comment: It won't show up in intellsense, so I can't implement it.

Comment: Then you are referencing the wrong assemblies or something.  Is this WPF?

Comment: This is an easy one to hit ... you aren't alone.  I hit this same issue with another beta library recently.  Took me hours to figure out what was wrong. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using .NET 3.0 or 3.5 SP1 ObservableCollection is in WindowsBase.dll.  In 4.0, it is in System.dll.

Comment: Thanks, this was it.  I forgot that reference doesn't get added with class libraries automatically.

Answer (score 1):

`ObservableCollection` lives in `System.Collections.ObjectModel` namespace. If you have included the right assemblies(which should be right by default) then it shouldn't be a problem.

One thing with generic types in VS Intellisense is that the IDE won't prompt you to include the right namespace until you fully type the generic arguments.

At this point, if you right click, the Resolve context menu wouldn't be there.

```
ObservableCollection
```

Once you fill in the generic arguments:

```
ObservableCollection<int>
```

Resolve context menu will be available and you can either add `using System.Collections.ObjectModel;` or modify `ObservableCollection<int>` to `System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<int>`.

Perhaps that's what you were seeing?